# Cannot reassign $this, PDO results

Tags: php

I have a structure like this:

```
class DataList { 
... 
 public function fetchData(){
 ...
 $this = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS,"DataList");
 }
}
```

I want the db query result to set member variables matching field names.
But I'm getting an error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot re-assign $this in C:\xampp\htdocs\adk3\classes\DataList.php
on line 11
```

Comment: I guess you want `$this->result = ...`

Answer (score 0):

`$this` is a read-only variable. It is just a pointer to current object, allowing you to access it's properties and methods. You can't assign anything to it.